# mysql - Grouping together rows where Count() less than percentage of total

Tags: mysql

I'm working on a database which keeps track of student records for an after-school education company, including enrollment into classes and information on the students.

What I am trying to do is write a query that can return the number of enrolled students we have from each school, but also to group together schools that contribute below a certain percentage of the total (I want to display the information in a chart, but we have a lot of schools where only 1 students comes from that school, and I don't want the chart to have 50 bars or pie slices etc.)

So instead of

```
+-------------+------------+
| School Name | # Students |
+-------------+------------+
| School A    |         52 |
| School B    |         27 |
| School C    |         15 |
| School D    |          2 |
| School E    |          1 |
| School F    |          1 |
+-------------+------------+
```

I would want

```
+---------------+------------+
|  School Name  | # Students |
+---------------+------------+
| School A      |         52 |
| School B      |         27 |
| School C      |         15 |
| Other Schools |          4 |
+---------------+------------+
```

Here is the simplified form of the query I have now, it works but it's somewhat redundant in querying the same information with multiple Selects. Is there anyway to reduce the redundancy?

```
SELECT @enrollmentSum := COUNT(StudentEnrollmentID) FROM StudentEnrollment;
SELECT SchoolName, COUNT(StudentEnrollmentID) ECount FROM Student
JOIN StudentEnrollment ON StudentEnrollment.StudentID = Student.StudentID
JOIN School ON Student.SchoolID = School.SchoolID
GROUP BY SchoolName
HAVING Ecount >= .025 * @enrollmentSum
UNION ALL
SELECT "Other Schools" as SchoolName, SUM(Ecount) as ECount FROM
(
    SELECT SchoolName, COUNT(StudentEnrollmentID) ECount FROM Student
    JOIN StudentEnrollment ON StudentEnrollment.StudentID = Student.StudentID
    JOIN School ON Student.SchoolID = School.SchoolID
    GROUP BY SchoolName
    HAVING Ecount < .025 * @enrollmentSum
) t2
ORDER BY Ecount DESC
```

If needed, the basic structure of the relevant tables:

**Student**

```
+-----------+-------------+----------+
| StudentID | StudentName | SchoolID |
+-----------+-------------+----------+
```

**School**

```
+----------+------------+
| SchoolID | SchoolName |
+----------+------------+
```

**StudentEnrollment**

```
+---------------------+-----------+---------+
| StudentEnrollmentID | StudentID | ClassID |
+---------------------+-----------+---------+
```

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tips:

- count(x) returns number of rows where "x IS NOT NULL" therefore count(primary key) = count(*) which is simpler to read
- "JOIN School ON Student.SchoolID = School.SchoolID" can be rewritten as "JOIN School USING (SchoolID)" which is more readable and also gives you only one column "SchoolID" in the result set if you use something like "select *"

Now, the query...

```
SELECT SchoolName, sum(cnt) ECount FROM 
(SELECT IF(count(*)>=.025*@enrollmentSum, SchoolName, 'Others') AS SchoolName,
 COUNT(*) cnt FROM Student
 JOIN StudentEnrollment USING (StudentID)
 JOIN School USING (SchoolID)
 GROUP BY SchoolName) subq
GROUP BY SchoolName
ORDER BY Ecount DESC
```

Using the IF() will replace school name with 'others' for all schools below the threshold. Note this is computed after the GROUP BY, so you can actually use count(*) in the selected expressions. Then another GROUP BY groups the 'others' together.

**EDIT**

This is quite a hack, but it seems to do what you want...

```
SET @total=0; 
SELECT IF(cnt/@total>=0.2, SchoolName, 'Others') SN, sum(cnt) FROM (
    SELECT SchoolName, cnt, @total:=@total+cnt FROM (
        SELECT SchoolName, count(*) cnt FROM st GROUP BY SchoolName
    ) AS foo -- ORDER BY cnt DESC
) AS bar
GROUP BY SN ORDER BY sum(cnt) DESC;
```

This is perversion. MySQL seems to always materialize subquery "foo" first and store the results in a buffer prior to processing subquery "bar". I thought "ORDER BY cnt DESC" was necessary, but it also seems to work if it is commented out.

Running subquery "foo" has the side effect of setting @total to the value we want!

Thus when the outer subquery is run, the total is available.

Problem with this approach is it could probably stop working without warning since it's a hack.

[Postgresql version if you're curiosus...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/851ce/11/0)

Comment: This works perfectly and very well-explained including the tips, thank you! Just one other thing, is there no way around using a separate query for the enrollmentSum variable?

Comment: I found a way, but it's ugly.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help, just trying to get a grasp on things and it isn't always easy to know if I'm following best practices or doing things completely wrong